# Xcode 4.4 changes to localization - how do I NOT localize main storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm localizing an app for the first time, and only need to localize my "Localizable.strings" file. To set that up I created the file, then selected it and pressed the "Make localized..." button and it let me add an English localization (I haven't added any other languages yet).

To my surprise, with Xcode 4.4, doing that also automatically localized these files, moving them into the "en.lproj" folder:

- InfoPlist.strings
- MainStoryboard.storyboard

I don't need or want to localize the storyboard file, as there's nothing in it that's language based... and as far as I know, I don't need to localize InfoPlist.strings either (unless I decide to localize the app name?).

So, how do I unlocalize a file?

I see there's an option for "Use base internationalization" which from my understanding would use a base main storyboard rather than localizing it. That sounds like what I need, but according to the Xcode 4.4 release notes that won't work on iOS projects:

> The Use Base Internationalization setting in the project editor works
>   only on Mac products for deployment on OS X v.10.8 and later. Xcode
>   must also be running on OS X v.10.8 or later. This setting is not
>   supported on iOS projects. 11712855

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/_index.html

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doing some testing... interestingly, when starting a new project with Xcode 4.4 it automatically creates the en.lproj localization with InfoPlist.strings and MainStoryboard.storyboard there. Adding French and Spanish languages, and having those NOT localize the storyboard seems to work (somehow, when using French or Spanish, it still loads the English storyboard, even though it's in that en.lproj folder).

Comment: Apple's localization always falls back to another language if it can't find a localized resource in the target language. Don't remember if it falls back to english specifically, or a smarter targeted base, but for english speaking devs you can expect it to fall to english.

Answer (score 1):

If you select a file and look at the info for that file. Under the "General" tap there is a section for localization with a +/- for the various languages. Just remove all the languages from there and it will no longer be localized.

Comment: You are mostly correct, but I think it's important to add one clarification: if you uncheck all of the languages, it deletes the storyboard file (though it does give you a chance to cancel). It doesn't automatically move the storyboard into the base directory... so you have to make a copy of the storyboard file first, then drag it back into your project after unchecking all of the languages. (I'm not sure if that's a better solution than just unchecking everything but English, as other languages still seem to be able to pick up the storyboard from that en.lproj folder).